# Mesh Translation in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx

I am currently working on an engine using DirectX - I am able to display meshes loaded externally, however my current method of creating a translation matrix does not effect the meshes when the program is run

The code in question is as follows

```
D3DXMATRIX matTranslate;

D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)

App.Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matTranslate)

Mesh->Render();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: Does changing the view or projection matrices affect anything? What does `Mesh->Render()` do exactly (Is it a standard function? Is it possible that it's setting the world matrix)?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, that function should actually read Mesh->DrawMesh(); which draws it onto the buffer as far as I'm aware. Following another tutorial, I removed the matrix code from the function it was in and placed it inside my begin_scene(); function but it's still displaying all of my meshes on top of each other

Comment: Check the shader (.HLSL,or .FX file) that is being used. When a shader is used, the matrix must be bound (passed) into the shader. Commonly shaders use the world matrix and other matrices derived from the world matrix (like WorldViewInverse and WorldViewProj) so be sure to update them properly too.